# Get /login: unsupported protocol scheme "" wth Cloud Foundry cli

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am getting the below error
Get /login: unsupported protocol scheme ""

when I am trying to login with cloud foundry cli..

I am typing cf login , it displays the api endpoint and the below error

```
Warning: Your targeted API's version (3.59.0) is less than the minimum supported API version (3.85.0). Some commands may not function correctly.

Get /login: unsupported protocol scheme ""
FAILED
```

Kindly help on this.

Comment: A few things: 1.) Run `cf login -v`. That should give you more debugging information which will likely provide clues. 2.) Your cf cli seems significantly newer than your target CF installation. Either upgrade your CF installation or try using an older cf cli version. Otherwise, the cf cli will fail when it requires a feature not available in your CF version.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa for the reply. I am pretty new to Cloud Foundry. Could you please tell me how I can upgrade my cf installation?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you installed it. It's not a simple question, and there's unfortunately not a simple answer. The best I can say is to refer to the documentation for the tool you used to install it. If you didn't install it, like you're using a public service or CF is operated by some other team at your company then you'd need to reach out to that team and request it. Hope that helps!

Comment: I uninstalled the the cli7 version and updated the default version which came out to be 6.53.0 and i am able to login with that.

Comment: Now when I am trying to change the endpoint I am getting the below error: Invalid JSON content from server: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Again, include output of what you're trying to do with the `-v` flag. That will provide details on what the cf cli is doing.

Comment: Able to figure it out.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

downgrade cli from 7.0 to 6.0. It worked for me

Comment: yes it worked me as well for version 6.0. The issue was with new version

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to v6 worked. Using homebrew:

```sh
brew uninstall cloudfoundry/tap/cf-cli@7

brew install cloudfoundry/tap/cf-cli
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).